# I tried to make the camera to move the same way in first person game but its not moving why?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

This is my Game1.cs code i marked the areas of the camera movement code parts:
Added the camera code in my Game1.cs i used the riemers tutorials camera code here:

```
http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Mouse_camera.php
```

I also tried the code in the bottom by user31911 but same results the camera pointer/cursor is dancing/shaking in the middle and not responding.

Im trying to use the Camera class to move the camera around using the mouse.

```
http://pastebin.com/SF3iiftq
```

In the constructor i have this line:

```
viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraFinalTarget, cameraRotatedUpVector);
```

If i use this line instead assign the viewMatrix variable later in my code then i dont see the terrain at all.

And the big main problem is that the mouse is not responding at all what i get is the mouse pointer dancing/shaking in the middle.
The only thing that responding is my ProcessInput method i did the keys there are working but the method ProcessInputCamera the kkeys and mouse there are not resopnding when im moving the camera the mouse cursor is shaking/dancing in the middle.

I can't figure out why it happen.

But the mouse is not moving the camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls edit your Question! There are to many unnecessary informations...

here is my camera (1st person) class

```
class Camera 
{ // up in here normal needed vars
public Vector3 cameraPosition; 
public float moveSpeed, rotateSpeed; 

public bool playing = true; 

public GraphicsDevice device; 

public Matrix view, projection; 

Matrix rotation; 

float yaw = 0; 
float pitch = 0; 

int oldX, oldY; 

public Camera(Vector3 cameraPosition, float moveSpeed, float rotateSpeed, float filedOfView, GraphicsDevice device, float PerspectiveFieldOfView) 
{ 
this.cameraPosition = cameraPosition; 
this.moveSpeed = moveSpeed; 
this.rotateSpeed = rotateSpeed; 

this.device = device; 

view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up); 
projection =  Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(PerspectiveFieldOfView), device.Viewport.AspectRatio, 0.1f, filedOfView); 

ResetMouseCursor(); 
} 

public void Update() 
{ 
KeyboardState kState = Keyboard.GetState(); // make is able to use your keys
Vector3 v = new Vector3(0, 0, -50) * moveSpeed; // let you permanent walk 
move(v);                                        // isnt essential could be deleted if you wont that
} 

if (kState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W)) 
{ 
Vector3 v = new Vector3(0, 0, -100) * moveSpeed; 
move(v); 
} 

if (kState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S)) 
{ 
Vector3 v = new Vector3(0, 0, 50) * moveSpeed; 
 move(v); 
} 

if (kState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)) 
{ 
Vector3 v = new Vector3(-50, 0, 0) * moveSpeed; 
 move(v); 
 projection = Matrix. 
 } 

if (kState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D)) 
{ 
Vector3 v = new Vector3(50, 0, 0) * moveSpeed; 
move(v); 
} 

pitch = MathHelper.Clamp(pitch, -1.5f, 1.5f); 
MouseState mState = Mouse.GetState(); 

int dx = mState.X - oldX;      /* is for turning you objekt / camera
yaw -= rotateSpeed * dx;        *
                                *
int dy = mState.Y - oldY;       *
pitch -= rotateSpeed * dy;      */

ResetMouseCursor();          // this makes your mouse "dancing" in the middle

UpdateMatrices(); 
} 

private void ResetMouseCursor() // mouse settings for the camera
{ 
int centerX = device.Viewport.Width / 2; 
int centerY = device.Viewport.Height / 2; 
Mouse.SetPosition(centerX, centerY); 
oldX = centerX; 
oldY = centerY; 
} 

private void UpdateMatrices() //standart camera things
{ 
rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(yaw) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch); 
Vector3 transformedReference = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(0, 0, -1), rotation); 
Vector3 lookAt = cameraPosition + transformedReference; 

view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, lookAt, Vector3.Up); 
} 

public void move(Vector3 v) // is the self programmed method to let you move
{ 
Matrix yRotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(yaw); 
v = Vector3.Transform(v, yRotation); 

cameraPosition += v; 
} 

}
```

It's pretty standart, but good.
In most cases this class is all you need for the Camera and it's configuration.
Rewrite/Fix it, like however you need it...

Tipp: You could also consider a Arc-Ball-Cam..

Comment: user31911 Ok i added this class and added to my Game1 variable of the class called it camera. then in the constructor i did: cameraPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, 5000.0f);
            camera = new Camera(cameraPosition, 10, 10, 20, device, 20);    and in the update method i did : camera.Update(); but its not moving i need to add/change anything else ?

Comment: of course ... !!
this line is essential ... but if you dont understand this class already... you should read a tutorial about it... if you are german i would know a very good one for you. just go on http://www.youtube.com/user/GermanXNATutorials and work through it... i used myself this class and change it as i need it :P . Don't forgert to vote my answers up / as accepted ;)

Comment: use understand able var pls... this is already right: cameraPosition = new Vector3(0.0f, 50.0f, 5000.0f); camera = new Camera(cameraPosition, 10, 10, 20, device, 20);... but camera.update(); isnt enough in most cases ... or mb your world is moving with you cause its uses the camera, too i would have to see it to help more

Comment: added comments in my code ... hopefully it will help you :3 ... should be enough now ... ;) im glad that i helped you ;D dont forget to vote my answer up !! :)

Comment: Here is a link to my complete project i added it to a rar file its not that big. Maybe someone can take a look at it. I still didnt make it to work. http://www.2shared.com/file/IkKmqBFZ/MyFirst3D.html

Comment: i could take a look on it ... you just will have to evening cause currently im at office ;)

Comment: sry but i would have to register on that page ... upload it on shareonline uploaded mega or an other hoster pls ... ;)

Comment: Uploaded it to my SkyDrive: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!313&authkey=!AHulSlLQk6XFkX0       Tell me if you was able to download it.

Comment: I've seen that my camera class do have a few issues ...but you could easily fix them and about your coding ... DONT PUT EVERYTHING in the game class -.- :D ,else it is veryhard to understand in the 1st sight... just try to use my class and you had put the rotation on the keys move(transformation i think was it called). After this you will have easier progress in your code so... if you will have done it show me your project again ... i will futher help you after this ^^